# How to relatively position groups of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a macro (example below) to create a 3x3 grid out of a list of 9 items, but if I try to draw two of them they sit on top of each other. I get that each is a different path and restarting at 0,0... looking for advice on the cleanest way to "package" them so I can draw them next to each other without thinking about their exact size.

Eventually I want to put them into a tree layout algorithm to  show a search tree for solving a 3x3 sliding puzzle (using this as an excuse to figure out how to use tikz). My guess is that I need to be able to package up the structure as one unit so that tikz can think of them as nodes to layout. Am I thinking about things the right way or not?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary[calc]
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\ninepuzzle}[1] {
    \foreach [count=\i] \val in {#1} { 
        \draw  let \n{row}={int(mod(\i -1, 3))}, \n{col}={ int( ( \i - 1 ) / (-3) ) } in 
            (\n{row}, \n{col}) rectangle  +(1,1) 
            +(0.5, 0.5) node{\val};
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \ninepuzzle{1,2, ,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    \ninepuzzle{8,5,6,3,2,4, ,1,7}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his answer, **Harish** has shown how to shift the puzzles. In this answer I want to show how you can use the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package to build the tree (notice that no shifting is required, although it could be easily done with the features provided by `forest`):

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary[calc]

\newcommand{\ninepuzzle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach [count=\i] \val in {#1} { 
        \draw  let \n{row}={int(mod(\i -1, 3))}, \n{col}={ int( ( \i - 1 ) / (-3) ) } in 
            (\n{row}, \n{col}) rectangle  +(1,1) 
            +(0.5, 0.5) node{\val};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}%    
}

\newsavebox\myboxa
\newsavebox\myboxb
\newsavebox\myboxc
\newsavebox\myboxd
\newsavebox\myboxe
\savebox\myboxa{\ninepuzzle{1,2, ,3,4,5,6,7,8}}
\savebox\myboxb{\ninepuzzle{8,5,6,3,2,4, ,1,7}}
\savebox\myboxc{\ninepuzzle{2,4,6,8,,1,3,5,7}}
\savebox\myboxd{\ninepuzzle{,1,2,4,5,3,6,8,7}}
\savebox\myboxe{\ninepuzzle{8,7,3,,4,6,5,1,2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
}
[\usebox\myboxa
  [\usebox\myboxb
    [\usebox\myboxd
    ]
    [\usebox\myboxe
    ]
  ]
  [\usebox\myboxc
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's only one thing that remains to be simplified and is the need to previously box each puzzle. In [Is it possible to use \node paths directly in forest?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179653/3954) (a question I opened inspired by this situation) I expect to get a way to not to have to do the boxing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `scope` with some `xshift`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary[calc]
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\ninepuzzle}[1] {
    \foreach [count=\i] \val in {#1} {
        \draw  let \n{row}={int(mod(\i -1, 3))}, \n{col}={ int( ( \i - 1 ) / (-3) ) } in
            (\n{row}, \n{col}) rectangle  +(1,1)
            +(0.5, 0.5) node{\val};
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \ninepuzzle{1,2, ,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \ninepuzzle{8,5,6,3,2,4, ,1,7}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Or you can use `pic` from `tikz` version 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary[calc,positioning]
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
ninepuzzle/.pic={
    \foreach [count=\i] \val in {#1} {
        \draw  let \n{row}={int(mod(\i -1, 3))}, \n{col}={ int( ( \i - 1 ) / (-3) ) } in
            (\n{row}, \n{col}) rectangle  +(1,1)
            +(0.5, 0.5) node{\val};
    }
    \coordinate (-mypoint) at (3,0); %% change (3,0) acc to  \n{row}={int(mod(\i -1, 3))} as 3 
}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \pic (a) {ninepuzzle={1,2, ,3,4,5,6,7,8}};
    \pic [right = of a-mypoint] {ninepuzzle={8,5,6,3,2,4, ,1,7}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]