# Is it possible to use \node paths directly in forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

The following simple example shows that when a `tikzpicture` is used directly as a `forest` node, some of its paths seem to be ignored: `\node` paths seem to be ignored while, for example `\draw` paths are treated as expected. One way to get the expected result it to previously box the pictures (the example also illustrates this); however, I need to use complex `tikzpicture`s containing `\node` paths directly in forest without previously boxing them. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand\test{\tikz{\node[fill=cyan!60] (a) {a};\draw[ultra thick,orange] (a.north west) -- (a.south east);}}
\savebox\mybox{\test}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[\test
  [\usebox\mybox
    [\test]
    [\test]
  ]
  [\test 
    [\usebox\mybox]
    [\usebox\mybox]
  ]
]    
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it sufficient to define node style with the crossed path?  If so I have a solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am after a solution that is as general as possible in which I can use general paths but perhaps your solution can be extended?

Comment: Ok.  I'll post it and then maybe we chat about it.

Comment: @AlanMunn OK. I'll be in the chat room in 20min. or so, and we can then discuss your solution in case you're there.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @cfr No. From time to time I think about this issue, but haven't really dedicated time to think about a solution. Do you perhaps have some idea?

Comment: How does it know where to draw the node?

Comment: @cfr in general, I'd expect to draw the `tikzpicture` as if it were a single tree node (in particular, taking into account height and width of the `tikzpicture`). Let me see if I can recover the problem that originally led me to ask this question.

Comment: @cfr No, I don't seem to be able to find the thread that motivated this question. In any case, it had to do with building a game tree; each node was supposed to be a different sudoku grid (or something similar). My first attempt was to use `tikz` to build the grids and then  `forest`, but placing directly the `tikzpicture`s as tree nodes produced unsatisfactory results.

Comment: @cfr It seems that forest isn't able to properly take into account the width and height of the elemets used as tree nodes if they are `tikzpicture`s (if I recall what the problem was, in the first place).

Comment: If you define `\test` without `\tikz` and say `tikz={\test}`, you get the nodes drawn almost correctly but in the wrong place. They are drawn at the root node. [I know this uses `tikz=` again, but it isn't splitting up the contents of the picture in the way the solution below does.] Even if the root has some other content, all of the `\test` things are drawn over it. I think this is because the value of `tikz` is passed to the `tikzpicture` environment as a whole. So if you could tell it where...? I don't really know. I asked because I was curious about a solution - not because I had one :(.

Comment: Would it work to box the contents on-the-fly and then include it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25022/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-cfr).

Comment: OK. But not tonight.... Sorry. Too late/early.

Comment: @cfr Of course. Whenever you can. The chat room was already created, so we can discuss there anytime. Have a good night/morning!

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution which uses the `tikz=` key to add the drawing part of the node specification.  I've put that into a style for the node.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
crossed/.style={fill=cyan!60, tikz={\draw[ultra thick,orange] (!.north west) -- (!.south east);}}
[A,for tree=crossed
  [B
    [C ]
    [D ]
  ]
  [E 
    [F ]
    [G ]
  ]
]    
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 10):

It *is* possible to use `\node` command directly in `forest`, via option `node format`. There are several caveats, though:

1. Node and only the node can be given in `node format`. In particular, adding a `\draw` or any `\path` after the node into `node format` is not possible. This is so because the node is typeset into a temporary box (in order to be measured) using PGF's deferred node positioning (`\pgfpositionnodelater` - `\pgfpositionnodenow`), which can only defer positioning of, well, nodes.

   So, Alan's suggestion to use option `tikz` is, as far as I see, the only generic way to add some TikZ code to the node. (And using relative node names to construct paths, like `(!.north west) -- (!.south east)`, is what I have done below, as well.)
2. The name given to the `\node` macro must match forest's `name` option. (Or, more precisely, they must match at the `draw tree stage`.) Otherwise, all hell will break loose.
3. The `\node` command in `node options` must be preceded by `\noexpand`. Why? `node format` must refer to the node's name, so it will contain `\forestoption{name}`, and by default, it also contains `\forestoption{node options}` and `\forestoption{content format}`. These macros must be expanded before `\node` is "called" (TikZ will not expand them "on the fly"), and this is precisely what happens just before the node is (deferredly) typeset. However, the `\node` macro itself should obviously not be expanded.

End of disclaimers, here's the code. (I have defined style `node format'` to ease entering the node specification. This style will find it's way into the upcoming v1.1 of the package.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  node format'/.style={
    node format={\noexpand\node(\forestoption{name})#1;}
  },
  test/.style={
    node format'={[fill=cyan!60] {a}},
    tikz={\draw[ultra thick,orange] (.north west) -- (.south east);},
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree=test
[
  [
    []
    []
  ]
  [ 
    []
    []
  ]
]    
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

P.S. Sorry to be answering a year and a half late ... I have completely missed this post.

Comment: PPS. So *that*'s how one becomes a necromancer! ;-)